# Tiny filesystem written in C

Tags: gratis, open-source, library, c, filesystems

I want a simple filesystem in pure C (no FUSE, or anything).

It needs directories, and files that can grow.

Specs of embedded system I want to use it on:

128KB of flash

64KB of RAM

RTOS available for threading, queues, and fixed-size memory allocation

No `malloc` available.

> Note: using a simple `read()` and `write()` interface would be nice, rather than direct buffer acces... this would make porting to my board easier.
>
> **Note 2: I am looking *for* a library, not to *make* a filesystem.**

Comment: `FAT12` is a tiny file system with directories and growable files. Try looking for it's implementation in `C`. The data-reading part should be included in every boot loader

Comment: @xmojmr thanks for the response! I don't want ChaN's library though..

Comment: The linux kernel (www.kernel.org) has C based implementations of many file systems including FAT12/16/32.  It has a subfolder named **fs** (file systems) and a subfolder **fat**.  Some amount of tweaking would be needed to get it to work for you, but it could probably be done.

Comment: @cybernard Thank you for the suggestion! I'm not a Linux programmer, though, and porting this might be difficult and it might be too big for my project.

Comment: How about lean fs  http://freedos-32.sourceforge.net/lean/

Comment: @cybernard I'll take a look at it.